# How to get OracleConnection in Oracle 12c WebLogic without specify IP weblogic server using Java Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic, oracle12c

I have to deploy WAR to oracle 12c weblogic server and access it's datasource. but i will deploy it in several weblogic server with different IP. is there any way to get connection to weblogic datasource without specify ip of the weblogic itself? assuming that the WAR is deployed in the same weblogic server and needed to access it's datasouce specified in the weblogic?

i can get oracle connection but must specify the IP. here is my code :

```
try{
    String urlparam = "t3://101.102.103.104:7001";
    String datasourceparam = "jdbc/devtest";

    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" );
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, urlparam);

    Context context=new InitialContext( env );
    ds=(javax.sql.DataSource) context.lookup (datasourceparam);
    conn=(OracleConnection) ds.getConnection();
    System.out.println("Connection object details : " + conn);
}
catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

If i use this method, to deploy to 5 weblogic servers, i have to generate 5 different WAR with only different IP weblogic server.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that to look at it's own datasource, i mustn't include hashtable environment in my InitialContext. this way, it will get specified datasource in itself.

```
try {    
    String datasourceparam = "jdbc/devtest";

    Context context = new InitialContext();
    ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) context.lookup(datasourceparam);
    conn = (OracleConnection) ds.getConnection();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle the exception
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```